# Assignment of UID and GID from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, uid, gid

My CentOS 7 machine has successfully joined a domain FOOBAR (as verified by `realm list`) and here's the information about an user coming from the AD (non-local):

```
[root@centos7 ~]# id jdoe@FOOBAR.GLOBAL
uid=5631533(jdoe@FOOBAR.GLOBAL) gid=5600513(domain users@FOOBAR.GLOBAL)
groups=5600513(domain users@FOOBAR.GLOBAL),5631532(othergroup@FOOBAR.GLOBAL)
```

How are UID and GID assigned?  Is it possible to somehow map them to some desired value?

Comment: I remember vaguelly something about being able to remap users...too long ago.

Comment: Are you using SSSD or winbind?

Comment: @ErikF Server is running sssd.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AD mapping in SSSD is determined using an algorithm (probably a hash function) in the daemon itself: because it's built-in, if you keep the defaults the same, every computer using SSSD should map the IDs to the same value regardless of the computer being used. Here's [Red Hat's explanation for the AD mapping:](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/windows_integration_guide/SSSD-AD#sssd-ad-proc)

> SSSD can use the SID of an AD user to algorithmically generate POSIX
>   IDs in a process called ID mapping. ID mapping creates a map between
>   SIDs in AD and IDs on Linux.
>
> - When SSSD detects a new AD domain, it
>     assigns a range of available IDs to the new domain. Therefore, each AD
>     domain has the same ID range on every SSSD client machine.
> - When an AD
>     user logs in to an SSSD client machine for the first time, SSSD
>     creates an entry for the user in the SSSD cache, including a UID based
>     on the user's SID and the ID range for that domain.
> - Because the IDs
>     for an AD user are generated in a consistent way from the same SID,
>     the user has the same UID and GID when logging in to any Red Hat
>     Enterprise Linux system.

You can set the ID minimums and maximums using [`min_id` and `max_id` in the [domain/*name*] section of sssd.conf.](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf) Look under "Domain Sections" for the description; "Examples" has an example of its use:

```
[sssd]
domains = LDAP
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2

[nss]
filter_groups = root
filter_users = root

[pam]

[domain/LDAP]
id_provider = ldap
ldap_uri = ldap://ldap.example.com
ldap_search_base = dc=example,dc=com

auth_provider = krb5
krb5_server = kerberos.example.com
krb5_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
cache_credentials = true

min_id = 10000
max_id = 20000
enumerate = False
```

If you override these values, make sure to set the same mappings on any other system using that domain in SSSD if you want to maintain consistent mappings!

Comment: Thank you for taking time to document this, very useful.