# What must be added to nsswitch.conf to show AD users and groups?

Tags: users, group, active-directory, getent

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/461565/assignment-of-uid-and-gid-from-active-directory).

I have a CentOS 7 machine which has joined a domain FOOBAR. It is possible to successfully get info about users stored in the AD via

```
id user@FOOBAR.GLOBAL
```

However, `getent passwd` and `getent group` do not show users and group defined in the AD.

These are the relevant lines in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
```

What needs to be added there?

Comment: My guess is that you did not turn on enumerate in sssd.conf. This is turned off for a reason however so you might want to do some research before turning it on.

Comment: @DougO'Neal Good guess. I've tested it and written a detailed answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by @Doug O'Neal in a comment, it was necessary to set

```
enumerate = true
```

in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`.

Now `getent passwd` and `getent group` show all users and groups defined in the AD.

Note that this option is often not recommended.  From `man sssd.conf`:

```
(...)
    enumerate (bool)
       Determines if a domain can be enumerated. This parameter can have one of the
       following values:

       TRUE = Users and groups are enumerated

       FALSE = No enumerations for this domain

       Default: FALSE

       Note: Enabling enumeration has a moderate performance impact on SSSD while enumeration
       is running. It may take up to several minutes after SSSD startup to fully complete 
       enumerations. During this time, individual requests for information will go directly
       to LDAP, though it may be slow, due to the heavy enumeration processing. Saving a large 
       number of entries to cache after the enumeration completes might also be CPU intensive
       as the memberships have to be recomputed.

       While the first enumeration is running, requests for the complete user or group lists
       may return no results until it completes.

       Further, enabling enumeration may increase the time necessary to detect network
       disconnection, as longer timeouts are required to ensure that enumeration
       lookups are completed successfully. For more information, refer to the man pages for 
       the specific id_provider in use.

       For the reasons cited above, enabling enumeration is not recommended, especially in 
       large environments.
(...)
```

Comment: It can also help to add the following line to /etc/nsswitch.conf: `initgroups:     files sss`

Comment: @MichaelStröder Can you explain how adding that line might solve the OP's problem?